# compute sum vector variable in loop - spss syntax

Tags: loops, vector, spss

I have a variable A and I would like to subtract all the 1001 elements of this variable as follows: `B[n] = A[n+1] - A[n]` using spss syntax.

My code:

```
compute ctord = $casenum .
vector tot(1001).
vector B(1001).
compute tot(ctord) = A.
execute.

loop #i = 1 to 1001.
compute B(#i)=tot(#i+1)-tot(#i).
end loop.
```

But this code is not working in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating the Variable `B[n] = A[n+1] - A[n]`, where `n` is your case number, you first need to compute `A[n+1]` as a new variable:

```
CREATE
/A_lead = LEAD(A,1).
```

Then you can compute B easily with:

```
COMPUTE B = A_lead - A.
EXECUTE.
```

After that, you can delete A_lead if you want to.

```
DELETE VARIABLES a_lead.
```